# Solve linear system with $A_{i,j} = \langle e_i, e_j\rangle^2$, edges of a tetrahedron

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, simplex

I have six vectors in $e_i\in\mathbb{R}^3$ that are the edges of a tetrahedron. Let us consider now the linear equation system $Ax=b$ with
$$
A_{i,j} = \langle e_i, e_j\rangle^2,\\
b_i = \langle e_i, e_i\rangle.
$$
[The $3\times 3$-system for a triangle has the exact solution $$x_1 = \frac{\langle e_2, e_3\rangle}{\langle e_1\times e_2, e_1\times e_3\rangle}.
$$ (The other components likewise.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854279/solve-linear-system-with-a-i-j-langle-e-i-e-j-rangle2)

Any ideas on how to approach this for a tetrahedron?

Comment: Something is wrong here for $3\times 3$ case. Let $e_i$ be the $i$-th column of the identity matrix. Then $A = I$, $b = [1, 1, 1]^T$, and $x = b$. But $x_1$ in given solution is 0.

Comment: We're talking about the edges of a tetrahedron, so it's always $6\times 6$.

Comment: An exact solution involves determinants of $6\times 6$ matrices. Is that good for you?

Comment: @Artino Generally it does, but this particular equation system has so much structure that I think it might not. Check out the solution of the triangle: The denominator is just the dot product of some of the edges. I'm hoping for something similar in tetrahedra.

Comment: Of course, but a $3\times3$ determinant can be written as a triple product of  vectors, while that is not possible for a $6\times6$ determinant. That leaves me dubious about the possibility of finding a nice formula similar to that of a triangle.

Comment: We can of course expect the denominator to contain more than two cross-products.